# Wordpress search form not passing get variables

Tags: wordpress, search, get

I have an issue where I am creating a simple custom search form in Wordpress 3.4 sitting in a template file.

```
<form method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php bloginfo('home'); ?>">
 <input type="text" value="" name="s" id="s" />
 <input type="hidden" name="search-type" value="vacancies" />
 <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>
```

Upon submitting it hits a search.php file where further processing takes place.

```
<?php print_r($_GET); ?>
```

The problem is that I cannot access the get variables in search.php. I can echo here so I know I'm definitely hitting search.php but my get array is empty every time.

Any ideas would be a big help. I feel I may be making a rookie mistake...

Comment: What is `bloginfo('home')` when rendered by php? Doesn't look like a valid param.

Comment: It prints out the blog root i.e. http://127.0.0.1/sitename, messing with this in any way breaks the search. The resulting url on the results page is http://127.0.0.1/sitename/search/'searchterm' with no get variables to speak of..

Comment: The search results page does not do any processing. It only displays search results. See http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Search_Page. You are going to have to get into the core WP files if you want to add/modify the actual search variables. I do not know how to do this.

Comment: No worries mate, I was afraid of that. Thanks though.

Comment: Really? There's no way to access the variables returned in the search form? I'm surprised. I need to fiter my search by CPT, so added a select element to the form, but I can't access the $_GET results. So annoying. I'm gonna look into this further.

Answer (score 1):

I was having this problem too. The theme I am using (Roots) does some fancy rewriting of the search page URLs. So, searching for "french holiday" will be `site.com/search/french+holiday` instead of `site.com/?s=french+holiday`.

If you can't see the variable in the URL, you won't be able to access it using `$_GET`.

I changed back to the standard URLs and can now access my `$_GET` values.

Hope that helps.

Comment: exactly the problem I encountered. disabled roots 'nice-search' and it works perfectly now. Thanks!